# Expo react native top tab navigation causing an unexpected app crash

Tags: expo

com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
in RNCViewPager
in PagerView
in Unknown
in PagerViewAdapter
in RCTView
in Unknown
in TabView
in MaterialTopTabView
in PreventRemoveProvider
in NavigationContent
in Unknown
in MaterialTopTabNavigator
in VerifyTopTabNavigation
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in SceneView
in RCTView
in Unknown
in DebugContainer
in MaybeNestedStack
in RCTView
in Unknown
in RNSScreen
in Unknown
in Suspender
in Suspense
in Freeze
in DelayedFreeze
in InnerScreen
in Screen
in SceneView
in Suspender
in Suspense
in Freeze
in DelayedFreeze
in RNSScreenStack
in ScreenStack
in NativeStackViewInner
in RNCSafeAreaProvider
in SafeAreaProvider
in SafeAreaProviderCompat
in NativeStackView
in PreventRemoveProvider
in NavigationContent
in Unknown
in NativeStackNavigator
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner
in MyStack
in Provider
in App
in RCTView
in Unknown
in RCTView
in Unknown
in AppContainer, js engine: hermes, stack:
761786
dispatch@1:

How to solve the appcrash